# Multiple webpack in angular cli configuration

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

Im trying to do tests with karma but a get an error :

```
ERROR in ./src/test.ts
Module build failed: Error: AotPlugin was detected but it was an instance of the wrong class.
This likely means you have several @ngtools/webpack packages installed. You can check this with `npm ls @ngtools/webpack`, and then remove the extra copies.
```

When I execute the cmd I get this result :

```
+-- @angular/cli@1.1.1
| `-- @ngtools/webpack@1.4.1
`-- @ngtools/webpack@1.5.1
```

In my `package.json` I only have `@ngtools/webpack": "^1.5.1`

Where is this 1.4.1 coming from ?

Comment: The answer is right before your eyes. It's a sub-dependency of the angular cli.

Answer (score 8):

I have seen this issue many many times. And previously I just solved randomly by accident. And today I just figured out that the reason why you see this message is because the @angular/cli version in your "devDependencies" in your package.json doesn't match with your dependencies' version. For example, after I run `npm ls @ngtools/webpack`, I see the following:
`atom-web-accessibility@1.0.0 /Users/jma/atom-web-accessibility
├─┬ @abot/atom-web-higgs@3.16.1
│ └─┬ @angular/cli@1.4.7
│   └── @ngtools/webpack@1.7.4
└─┬ @angular/cli@1.7.3
  └── @ngtools/webpack@1.10.2`

So now I have to go to my package.json, under `"devDependencies"`, change the version number `"1.7.3"` to be `"1.4.7"`. Then run the following:
`rm -rf node_modules`

`rm -rf package-lock.json`

`npm cache clean -f`

`npm install`

`ng build`

`npm start`

then I see `webpack: Compiled successfully.`

tada!!!! Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, This is definitely the way to go. Same answer as @alexKhymenko but more detailed

Answer (score 4):

Its comming from angular cli. Remove yours from package json. Reinstall modules. And it will work.

Comment: It happens to all of us :-) No problem

Comment: reinstalling, deleteing node_modules folder, clearing npm cache etc did not fix it. currently i am using `"@angular/cli": "^1.7.0"` `npm ls @ngtools/webpack` shows only one webpack...Error is: `Module build failed: Error: Angular Compiler was detected but it was an instance of the wrong class.
This likely means you have several @ngtools/webpack packages installed.`

Answer (score 0):

To remove it from the dependencies in package.json, you will need to use the save flag:

```
npm uninstall --save webpack
```

If you have installed the package as a "devDependency" (i.e. with `--save-dev`) then `--save` won't remove it from package.json. You need to use `--save-dev` to uninstall it.
Here is the outcome of the above command

```
$ npm ls @ngtools/webpack
angularapp@0.0.0 C:\Apache24\htdocs\angularapp
+-- @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.7.5
| `-- @ngtools/webpack@6.1.5
`-- @ngtools/webpack@6.2.1
```

---

```
$ npm uninstall --save webpack
> node-sass@4.9.3 install C:\Apache24\htdocs\angularapp\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Cached binary found at C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\node-sass\4.9.3\win32-x64-59_binding.node

> node-sass@4.9.3 postinstall C:\Apache24\htdocs\angularapp\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

Binary found at C:\Apache24\htdocs\angularapp\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-59\binding.node
Testing binary
Binary is fine
added 1106 packages in 677.641s
```

---

```
$ npm ls @ngtools/webpack
angularapp@0.0.0 C:\Apache24\htdocs\angularapp
`-- @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.7.5
  `-- @ngtools/webpack@6.1.5
```